# value from database not visible in textbox and insert value to the right username

Tags: c#, mysql, database, textbox, sql-insert

As of now here is my code:

```
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection("Data Source = 'PAULO'; Initial Catalog=ShoppingCartDB;Integrated Security =True"))
            {
                scn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest =
                     CAST(REPLACE(CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) 
                     FROM CreditRequests Where Username=@Username;
                     SELECT CreditRequest FROM UserData 
                     WHERE Username=@Username", scn);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Session["New"];

                object value = cmd.ExecuteScalar();

                if (value != null)
                    txtCredit.Text = value.ToString();
            }
            }
        }
```

However, when i look at my database, the credit request value is being inserted to the database and makes new ID's and everything is `NULL`.

Example

```
ID NULL Username NULL Email NULL Contact NULL Creditrequest 5,000
```

Is there a way to insert the credit request value to the right username. What am i missing in my code?

Also, i want that credit request value to be shown in my textbox and i believe its this line of code?

```
if (value != null)
    txtCredit.Text = value.ToString();
```

Comment: You seem to not understand the proper concepts of SQL. Please take a look here: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Specifically, check out the `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and  `SELECT`, and learn what they do, and when you should use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling an INSERT statement that adds a new record. And no, adding a WHERE clause at the end, doesn't transform an insert statement in an update statement.

If you want to UPDATE an existing record then you call

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest =
                     (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) 
                     FROM CreditRequests c Where c.Username=@Username)", scn);
```

For the second part of your question, is not possible to get the return value of ExecuteScalar in this context because UPDATE doesn't select any record to return. If you want to get back that value you could issue two statement together separating them with a semicolon:

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest =
                     (SELECT CAST(REPLACE(c.CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) 
                     FROM CreditRequests c Where c.Username=@Username);
                     SELECT CreditRequest FROM UserData u
                     WHERE u.Username=@Username", scn);
```

Both statements will be executed, but ExecuteScalar will be able to return the CreditRequest updated

Comment: ("UPDATE UserData SET CreditRequest = SELECT CAST(REPLACE(CreditRequest, ',', '') as int) FROM CreditRequests Where Username=@Username", scn);

Comment: Yes SELECT could be removed

Comment: remove the select? now the error is near the cast sir

Comment: Uhm, what version of Sql Server are you using?

Comment: SSMS is the administrative tool. The version of SQL Server could be read running  SELECT @@version in a query window of SSMS

Comment: tried the second statement. error is Ambiguous column name 'Username'.

Comment: SQL 2008 sir steve

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113420/discussion-between-steve-and-paolo-duhaylungsod).

Comment: Sorry but for some strange reason Microsoft Edge doesn't allow me to authenticate in chat

Comment: i tried the second statement sir. it gives me an error "Ambiguous column name 'Username'"

Comment: Please rollback the question to its original text. Changing the original question to a new version makes difficult to follow the logic of answers and comments. For example, now the main problem in your question is another one and my answer seems completely wrong.

Comment: Please go to the chat now

Comment: Sir steve can you help me out on this? pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37562604/avoid-local-host-id-to-be-edited-by-customers